# Is there a way to check the sequence of element in Selenium Web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Actually I am trying to the test the Order in the contact. so basically, I am checking the order in the contact tab like Name, Email Address, Phone Number, Message. Here is the like https://anyaut.com/

```
myD = new ChromeDriver(); 
myD.get("https://anyaut.com/"); 
myD.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Contact US')]")).click(); myD.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='c_name')]")).findElement(By.xpath("./following-sibling:://input[@id='c_email']"));
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to automate layout testing, i.e. validate not only presence of the [DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/introduction.html) elements but also their location, order, size, applied styles, etc. - it's better to consider using [Galen Framework](http://galenframework.com/)

Theoretically you can achieve the same using vanilla Selenium and [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) locators which have full access to DOM tree, however it will be quite hard to develop and maintain, moreover this approach will be very fragile due to high sensitivity to markup changes while in Galen framework you can define the pass/fail criteria using simple declarative syntax

```
@objects
    comments            #comments
            article-content     div.article

            = Main section =
@on mobile, tablet
        comments:
        width 300px
        inside screen 10 to 30px top right
        near article-content > 10px right

@on desktop
        comments:
        width ~ 100% of screen/width
        below article-content > 20px
```

More information:

- [Galen Framework Tutorial: First Project](http://galenframework.com/docs/tutorial-first-project/)
- [The 7 Best Practices for Visual Testing with the Galen Framework](https://experitest.com/web-testing/the-7-best-practices-for-layout-testing-with-the-galen-framework/)
- [The Art Of Layout Testing With Galen Framework](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/06/the-art-of-layout-testing-with-galen-framework/)